# Loading data from external json file with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, load

I'm looking into dynamically using data from an external json file into my javascript.
I must have misunderstood how to call the file because for the moment I can't even access the data...
So theres my html calling the js file. and the js file calls the json using this method :

```
$(function() {
    function stockTimeline(){
        $.getJSON('json/corse_timeline/corse_timeline.json', function(donnees) {
            $('#wrap').html('<p>' + donnees.timeline.date[4].endDate + '</p><p>' + donnees.timeline.date[9].startDate + '</p><p>' + donnees.timeline.headline + '</p><p>' + donnees.timeline.date[30].headline + '</p><p>');
            console.log("this console.log IS NOT working");
        });
        console.log("this console.log IS working");
    }
    stockTimeline(); 
});
```

I've taken this method right out of several tutorials I've read.
How can I test if my json file is corrupted?
Is it because I need to upload it on a server for it to work?

Comment: Does the console show any javascript errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can verify your JSON file by pasting it into [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: I do have tons of parse error! thanks for the link, I'm correcting it right now ;)

Comment: Handy stuff. Sometimes you just need fresh eyeballs, even if they are those of a machine.